# Java - Error: cannot find symbol - variable

Tags: java, parsing, bluej

I'm trying to write a method on java that takes a string and returns the first character to a char variable and the numbers i the string to a integer variable. The strings will always follow the format of one character and one/two numbers (eg C25 or C5). It compiles but when i call the method I get the error: Error: cannot find symbol - variable C5. C5 being the string I input.

```
    import java.lang.*;
    public class Term
{
    private char element;
    private int  atoms;

    // creates a Term with the provided values
    public Term(char element, int atoms)
    {
        this.element = element;
        this.atoms = atoms;
    }


   // creates a Term by parsing s 
   // e.g. "H20" would give element = 'H', atoms = 20 
    public Term(String s)
    {
        if (s.length() > 1) {
        int x = Integer.parseInt(s);
        char y = s.charAt(0);
        this.atoms = x;
        this.element = y;
        } else {
        this.element = s.charAt(0);
        }

    }

    // turns the Term into a String 
    // e.g. element = 'C', atoms = 4 would give "C4"
    public String display()
    {
        String rtnstr;
        rtnstr = "";
        if (atoms > 1 || atoms != 0) {
            String str1 = Character.toString(element);
            String str2 = String.valueOf(atoms);
            rtnstr = str1 + str2;
        } else if (atoms == 1) {
        rtnstr = Character.toString(element);
        } else if (atoms == 0) {
        rtnstr = "Error, zero atoms present in term.";
        }
        return rtnstr;
    }

    // returns the current value of element 
    public char getElement()
    {
        return element;
    }

    // returns the current value of atoms 
    public int getAtoms()
    {
        return atoms;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The code you've provided wouldn't create the error you've described... please provide a [mcve].

Comment: That still isn't a [mcve], and won't give the error you've described.

Comment: how are you testing that..???

Comment: Is this all of the code?  Where's the `main` method?

Comment: The program compiles without any errors, when I create a new object (using: new Term(char element, int atoms)) in blueJ and enter the values, I get this error.

Comment: I don't think the problem lies in what you've posted here.  I strongly suspect you're using BlueJ incorrectly - are you putting single quotes around the C?

Comment: @DavidWallace you are correct, thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that the format will always be one character and one/two numbers (eg C25 or C5) you can do this

```
public Term(String s) {
    this.element = s.charAt(0);
    this.atoms = Integer.parseInt(s.subString(1));
}
```